# dividir index en varios archivos

Tags: html, datatables

Hola vamos a ver si me explico bien:

Tengo una web con una tabla en html y tiene muchas entradas y el archivo index.php empieza a pesar mucho, ya que contiene muchas lineas de código.

¿hay alguna manera de dividir este archivo en varios html index1.php index2.php por ejemplo, para asi reducir el tamaño del index.php?

por cierto uso el script de [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)

### ejemplo de mi codigo

### html

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>
```

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar `require();`

```
<?php
require('index2.php');
?>
```

o `include();`

```
<?php 
include 'index3.php';
?>
```

Te incluyo la diferencia entre estos mismos:

**require()** establece que el código del archivo invocado es requerido, es decir, obligatorio para el funcionamiento del programa. Por ello, si el archivo especificado en la función require() no se encuentra saltará un error «PHP Fatal error» y el programa PHP se detendrá.

**include()**, por el contrario, si no se encuentra dicho código, saltará un error tipo «Warning» y el programa seguirá ejecutándose (aunque como consecuencia de no incluirse el código puede que no funcione correctamente, o sí, depende de la situación).

Adicional mente y como consejo te recomiendo que investigues mas sobre el patrón de arquitectura de software como **MVC** Modelo Vista Controlador, el cual te permitirá separar la lógica de negocio y los datos, también organizaras de una mejor manera tus archivos